# Mysql searching

Tags: mysql, sql, search

ive come to a problem, the problem is, there is different system of date in our country. now i have to select the rows from one date to the other, it is similar to international date system but our months have irregular number of days, so i have made a table which involves date having one column of year and other of month
now i want to select all the rows from year 2069 of month 4 to year of 2070 of month 3 that means, we have to select all the records having year of 2069 and month of >=4 after that, all the year of 2070 and month of <3 so this is the problem, sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE (year = 2069 and month >= 4)
   OR (year = 2070 and month < 3)
```

Comment: will it work for WHERE (year >= 2069 and month >= 4)
   OR (year <= 2070 and month < 3)